# Copy data between MPI communicators

Tags: c++, c, mpi

I have split MPI_COMM_WORLD into two sub-communicators and I want to transfer an array of data distributed over MPI_COMM_WORLD to two sub-communicators. What is the best way to do that within MPI-1.1?

For example, there is an array `A = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]` distributed among four MPI processes in MPI_COMM_WORLD as follows

```
rank 0: [1 2] 
rank 1: [3 4] 
rank 2: [5 6] 
rank 3: [7 8]
```

I split MPI_COMM_WORLD into two sub-communicators constsing of two MPI processes each and want to have my data being like:

```
subcommunicator1:

    rank 0: [1 2 3 4]
    rank 1: [5 6 7 8]

subcommunicator2:

    rank 0: [1 2 3 4]
    rank 1: [5 6 7 8]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a way to send data from one communicator to another. In MPI, communicators specifically are designed to contain communication within groups. In your case, you'll need to distribute your data before you split up `MPI_COMM_WORLD`. How you do that will be dependent on your data and desired distribution. You'll probably need to look at `MPI_SCATTER`, `MPI_GATHER`, or both.

Comment: There's a site with some pretty good tutorials available at: http://mpitutorial.com/ (and though it is written by "Wes", it's not the same one as me)

Comment: *There isn't a way to send data from one communicator to another.* Surely each process retains its membership (and rank) in `MPI_COMM_WORLD` so that messages can continue to be passed between processes in different (sub-)communicators ?  Or have I missed something ?  It's a long time since I used groups and inter communicators.

Comment: Of course, you're correct Mark. You can continue to send data on the original communicator after you've created the subcommunicators. The point is that you'll have to do that sort of data transfer on `MPI_COMM_WORLD` rather than on some other communicator that you've created.

Comment: Wesley, thank you. I was hoping there is a way to do it semi-automatically.

Comment: Am late for this, I thought linking MPI_COMM_WORLD and subcommunicator* with an inter communicator ( `mpi_intercomm_create`)  could help.